# How to allow to steal locks only to a specific Active Directory domain group with VisualSVN Server?

Tags: svn, powershell, active-directory, hook, visualsvn-server

Development team that uses [Subversion's locking feature](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/locking/) and VisualSVN Server with Active Directory authentication ([Integrated Windows Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_windows_authentication) or [Basic Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)) may need to restrict anyone except administrators to [steal locks](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/locking/#svn.advanced.locking.break-steal).

Such task can be achieved with a [pre-lock hook](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/reposhooks/pre-lock/). However since the authentication relies on Active Directory users and groups, writing such a script can be a bit tricky.

Also there may be other cases when certain AD users' actions must be processed by a hook script differently based on their AD domain groups membership.

Is there any sample that show how to check AD domain group membership with a Subversion hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check AD group membership with the sample PowerShell pre-lock hook script provided below.

The *pre-lock.ps1* PowerShell script checks whether the user is a member of the **Administrators** Active Directory group and denies to steal lock if the user is not a member of the group.

Put both *pre-lock.bat* and *pre-lock.ps1* into your repository 'hooks' folder, e.g. `C:\Repositories\repository\hooks\`.

***pre-lock.ps1***

```
# Function check if $user is a member of $group
function Check-GroupMembership
{
  param([string]$group, [string]$user)

  $server = get-content env:COMPUTERNAME
  $query = [ADSI]("WinNT://$server/$group,group")

  $ulist = $query.psbase.invoke("Members") |`
           %{$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}

  $ulist -contains $user
}

# Store hook arguments into variables with mnemonic names
$repos     = $args[0]
$path      = $args[1]
$user      = $args[2]
$comment   = $args[3]
$steallock = $args[4]

# Build path to svnlook.exe
$svnlook = "$env:VISUALSVN_SERVER\bin\svnlook.exe"

# Get the lock description
$lockdescr = (&"$svnlook" lock $repos $path)

# Find owner name
foreach ($str in $lockdescr)
{
  if ($str.StartsWith("Owner: "))
  {
    $owner = $str.Substring(7)

    # We find lock owner's name and it is not the user name
    if ($owner -ne "" -and $owner -ne $user)
    {
      # If the $user is a member of 'Administrators'
      # group allow to steal the lock
      if (-not (Check-GroupMembership "Administrators" $user))
      {
        [Console]::Error.WriteLine("Error: $path already locked by $owner.")
        exit 1
      }
    }

    exit 0
  }
}

exit 0
```

***pre-lock.bat***

```
@echo off
set PWSH=%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
%PWSH% %1\hooks\pre-lock.ps1 %1 %2 %3 %4 %5
if errorlevel 1 exit %errorlevel%
```

Comment: It's better to use VISUALSVN_SERVER environment variable to get path to svnlook.exe to be compatible with x64 OS. I.e. $svnlook = "$env:VISUALSVN_SERVER\bin\svnlook.exe"

Comment: Thank you! I've adjusted the sample code to make use of %VISUALSVN_SERVER% environment variable.